# Mounting Windows dynamic disk in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dynamic-disk

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I assumed I would be able to mount my Dynamic Data Disk as RO. So, after installing ubuntu, I installed ldmtool and entered: show DiskGroup ... which returned

```
  ldm> show diskgroup fd58d19d-5fc9-11e6-aaa4-086266b942c1
{
  "name" : "NOAHVT-N551VW-Dg0",
  "guid" : "fd58d19d-5fc9-11e6-aaa4-086266b942c1",
  "volumes" : [
    "Volume2",
    "Volume3"
  ],
  "disks" : [
    "Disk1"
  ]
}
```

After entering "Create All" it said that it was able to mount Volume 3 (the least important to me :/) but was unable to mount Volume 2 because:

```
Unable to create volume Volume2 in disk group fd58d19d-5fc9-11e6-aaa4-086266b942c1: Partition volume offset does not match sizes of preceding partitions
```

Doing show volume on Volume 2 returns:

```
    ldm> show volume fd58d19d-5fc9-11e6-aaa4-086266b942c1 Volume2
{
  "name" : "Volume2",
  "type" : "spanned",
  "size" : 489205760,
  "chunk-size" : 0,
  "hint" : "G:",
  "partitions" : [
    "Disk1-01",
    "Disk1-02",
    "Disk1-04"
  ]
}
```

I also tried a Win VM in virtualbox but virtualbox VM's don't have access to actual drives.

Is there any way to save the data of this disk without going back to Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a dynamic disc for testing, but using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/483011/479613) I found that I can mount partitions on my GPT disc from the raw disc device:

```
mount -o offset=<offset in bytes> /dev/sda /mnt/<mount point>
```

If you can find the offset to the start of the partition, then multiply it by the sector size (usually 512 bytes) and use this offset in the mount command.

I don't know if `ldm` or any of the normal Ubuntu disc utilities will give you this information. If not:-

- try a Windows-based diagnostic disc, such as [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), which is XP-based; or
- the recovery disc for one of the standard disc back-up suites (such as Norton Ghost or Paragon) may give you this information.

If either of these boot discs sees the dynamic disc partitions, you also have the option to copy the partitions you need to a differently formatted partition, which you can access normally.

Without a dynamic disc I can't be more definitive, but I hope I have given you some pointers as to how you may proceed.